# Zooming Excel displayed in ole withing vb6

Tags: excel, vb6

I have an Excel spreadsheet displayed within an old VB6 application using OLE but recently the table is displayed very small for some reason. I did not change the code recently as far as I know and the problem seems to be only on users' computers.

Is there any way of forcing the size of display?

Changing the scale in the template file makes no difference.
Changing the sizemode makes no difference:

```
olePumpDetails.CreateLink g_strRangePumpDocumentation & strTemplate

If Not m_bDetailsExcelError Then
   Set oBook = olePumpDetails.object
   Set osheet = oBook.Sheets(1)
   SetDetailExcelValues oBook, osheet
   olePumpDetails.Refresh
End If
```

Elsewhere in the project on resize of form:

```
If olePumpDetails.Visible = True Then
   olePumpDetails.Visible = False
   olePumpDetails.Move 100, 400, Me.Width - 300, Me.Height - 1000 
   lblPumpDetailsError.Move (Me.ScaleWidth / 2) - (lblPumpDetailsError.Width / 2), lblPumpDetailsError.Top, lblPumpDetailsError.Left, lblPumpDetailsError.Top
   olePumpDetails.Visible = True
End If
```

I expected the spreadsheet to be displayed normal size.

Answer (score 0):

The Window object has a read / write [Zoom property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.zoom).

From the Microsoft Office Dev Center:

> Returns or sets a Variant value that represents the display size of the window, as a percentage (100 equals normal size, 200 equals double size, and so on).

```
If Not m_bDetailsExcelError Then
   Set oBook = olePumpDetails.object
   Set osheet = oBook.Sheets(1)
   SetDetailExcelValues oBook, osheet
   oBook.Windows(1).Zoom = 200  'set the default zoom
   olePumpDetails.Refresh
End If
```